# MySQL string values for tinyint types - PHP PDO built

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, types

In a project I have the following mySql query:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (status) VALUES ('')
```

where 'status' is of type tinyint(1).
The project is deployed on several different servers with varying PHP-versions and varying mySql versions.
Now - for the first time - we have the problem that on a new server the query above will result in an error

```
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'status' at row 1
```

Changing the query to

```
INSERT INTO my_table (status) VALUES ('0')
```

resolves the issue.
However it would be a pain to go through the whole project and change this sort of query everywhere.
The query is built by PDO with

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (status) VALUES (:status)");
$stmt->execute( array( ':status' => false ) );
```

or new style

```
$stmt->execute( array( ':status' => '0' ) );
```

Is there any way to tell PDO to behave differently when false gets passed in or can we set any parameters for the DB to handle empty strings differently when getting them for int-inputs?
Any ideas are very wellcome :-)

Also - it would be very interesting to know which version of MySQL (or PDO?) is the first one that could give us this problem?

Comment: `'0'` is still a string. Why don't you change it to `0` (a "true" number) if you're already at changing it?

Comment: @stickybit your are right. It should not be a string...

Comment: Disabling MySQL strict mode *may* allow you to store an empty value in a tinyint field but this is why it's best to develop with strict mode on.

Comment: @Devon hm... like I said: we didn't have any problems with this type of query so far (until now). So some default setting (or outdated version implication) seems to allow it regularly...

Comment: @user3440145 and did you look into strict mode like I said?

Comment: @Devon I can't really in this case. I would have to change the setting on a customers server - which is not an option here. Also it wouldn't be suitable for the future to have strict mode to be off as a requirement.

Comment: @user3440145  Not sure what you want then.  You said you wanted a solution to avoid having to update the code, that would probably be disabling strict mode.  If you don't want to disable strict mode, you have to update the code to handle strict mode.  I don't think there is an answer to this question.

Comment: @Devon thanks - that could be the answere I was looking for :-) Strange is that this problem did not occure until now. And can't really imagine that ALL DB's had strict mode off who used the app (I can not verify it - but it seems nearly impossible). So if changing the code is the only option - I will have to do that.

Comment: It could be worth checking, if `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` could cause this.